# How to write a title/abstract spanning 2 columns in 3-column page using multicol?

Tags: titles, multicol

My article requires that I put the title and a small abstract spanning the left 2 columns in a 3-column page, that is, the 3rd column to the right of the title/summary block must follow with the body text from the second column at the end of the page. I'm using `multicol` package.
This problem is easy and has been solved for 2-column page, either with `twocolumn` option in `\documentclass` or `multicol`.

Comment: Do you *have* to use [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) or is an alternative also sufficient?

Comment: Not specifically; I may try an alternative as long as it does a neat job.

Answer (score 5):

The [`flowfram` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) allows for this sort of thing without much problem. The following is taken partially from [Three-columns text with figures of `2\columnwidth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70175/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{flowfram}% http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

% First page setup    
\newstaticframe[1]{0.65\textwidth}{0.35\textheight}
  {0pt}{0.65\textheight}[titleabstract]
\newflowframe[1]{0.30\textwidth}{0.65\textheight}
  {0pt}{0pt}[shortleftcolumn]
\newflowframe[1]{0.30\textwidth}{0.65\textheight}
  {0.35\textwidth}{0pt}[shortcentercolumn]

% Subsequent pages setup    
\newflowframe[2-30]{0.30\textwidth}{\textheight}
  {0pt}{0pt}[leftcolumn]
\newflowframe[2-30]{0.30\textwidth}{\textheight}
  {0.35\textwidth}{0pt}[centercolum]
\newflowframe{0.30\textwidth}{\textheight}
  {0.7\textwidth}{0pt}[rightcolumn]

\begin{document}

\begin{staticcontents*}{titleabstract}
\begin{center}
  {\Large\bfseries This is the title\par}
  A.\ N.\ Author \par
  \today
\end{center}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{staticcontents*}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

The title and abstract is contained within the first `\newstaticframe` called `titleabstract`, which has a height of `0.35\textheight`. If you which to add more content, you may have to increase this, and decrease the height of `shortleftcolumn` and `shortcentercolumn`.

Comment: This one does the job, but is there a more generic way to do it, as in it calculates the textwidth and textheight automatically based on the number of columns it should span? Put another way, how to make a text block span n columns in an m-column page layout (using multicol if still possible)?

Comment: @mp1508: Not that I know of. Although it might be possible to calculate the height of the abstract and use that to determine the height of the `abstract` static frame, you'd still have to manually figure out the shorter/taller columns on the first page.