# How to fix a figure at the top or bottom of a column within multicol?

Tags: floats, positioning, multicol

Within the `multicol` environment I want to be able to fix a `figure` to be displayed at either the top or bottom of a column (as in a scientific journal).

The `figure` environment cannot be used in `multicol` and I've tried using `wrapfig` and even creating a `minipage` to do this, but the `figure` always seems to be placed where it is inserted in the text and therefore must be moved every time an edit is made.

Is there a way to force a `figure` to be positioned at the top or bottom of a column in `multicol`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: You may need something a little more "flexible". [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) can be of help here. See [Three-columns text with figures of 2`\columnwidth`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70175/5764) and [How to write a title/abstract spanning 2 columns in 3-column page using multicol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82031/5764).

Comment: Would you consider _"Switch from `multicol` to `twocolumn`"_ a valid answer?

Comment: @tohecz I want the columns on the final page to be equal length and   two column doesn't do this.

Comment: @MikeLaury My experience is that precise balancing of the columns on the final page is often quite problematic (imagine having 3 lines on the last page, how do you balance them?). I therefore prefer manual balancing of the last page, which can be done by issuing `\raggedbottom\enlargethispage{-0.2\textheight}`, where you modify `0.2` to a value such that the output looks nice. The only real drawback of this method is when you have chapters because then you must do it for each chapter. But who has a twocolumn document with chapters?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57732/placing-figures-inside-a-two-column-document/57750#57750

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the design of the package `multicol` does not allow this, and *cannot* allow this.

I can think of only one other option, and that is using the standard `[twocolumn]` class option or `\twocolumn` command. The true problem is then the column balancing on the last page. There are several possible solutions to this problem.

1. **Manually balance the columns.** This can be done by issuing the following commands *in the first column of the last page* (the value `0.2` has to be adjusted manually):

   ```
   \raggedbottom\enlargethispage{-0.2\textheight}
   ```
2. **Use the [package `cuted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cuted).** The following commands ought to be added *at the very end of the document*. The only issue is that if the last page is almost full, an extra completely empty page might be created. The commands are:

   ```
   \setlength{\stripsep}{-\baselineskip}\begin{strip}\end{strip}\leavevmode
   ```
3. **Use the [package `balance`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/balance).** However, this package is not reliable and corrupts vertical spacing. The usage is simple: issue the command `\balance` in the first column of the last page.

Or of course, you can wait for the LaTeX3 team to finish the new output routine `xor`, but this can take some time.

Comment: Prod Frank: `xor` can almost certainly do this, we just need to get it to production standard!

Comment: Thee is also `flushend` package for balancing.

Comment: @HarishKumar with its issues similar to `balance`.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is something along these lines:

```tex
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{4}

        % ===== First TWO columns of content =====

        \lipsum[1-5]
        \columnbreak
        
        \lipsum[1-5]
        \columnbreak

        % ===== End of my first two columasn =====
        
        % Fill the third column, which I want blank:

        \vfill\null
        \columnbreak
        
        % include graphics in minipage, set the anchor to top, then use \raggedleft
        % to produce an image at the bottom-right of my last column / the page:

        \vspace*{\fill}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
            \raggedleft
            \includegraphics[width=40px]{{myImg.png}}
        \end{minipage}
    
    \end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

As I write in the code's comments, I use a combination of what is mentioned on this and similar posts, where I use `\vfill\null` and `\columnbreak` to produce an empty column. Then, in the final column, in my situation, I am interested in an image at the bottom of the column, seated on the right side (it looks as though it sits on the bottom right corner of the page). Thus I use the combination of `\vspace*{\fill}` to fill the column's vertical space and a minipage anchored with `t` to place the image without being cut off the bottom of the page. Within the minipage I use `\raggedleft` to get the horizontal alignment I desire.

***Please note that, in the following image, the layout of my page (e.g. is horizontal) is due to this being in the mid of an active project of mine.***

[image: image of described scenario]