# flowfram package - balance 3 columns and extend columnsep line to end of text

Tags: flowfram

**Problem:** I [asked a question recently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/636941/245306) about putting a 2 column abstract and title within a 3 column document for which [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/636978/245306) provided an answer that worked as intended followed by helpful comments. The issue I face when putting the code into my main document is two things: 1) The `\columnsep` lines extend fully down the page irrespective of how much content is on the page and 2) I cannot see a way to balance the columns and have the sep lines extend only to the end of the balanced text. My knowledge on `flowfram` is limited and I am not sure if this is possible, but ideally I would like for my literature reviews to resemble the second picture and not first if possible.

**How it currently looks:**

[image]

**How I would like the balancing and line extensions to look if possible:**

[image]

**What I have tried:** Admittedly, very little as I do not understand `flowfram` although I will have to at some point as the package is useful. I tried using the package `flushend` but after reading the documentation, this only applies to double columns.

**MWE (courtesy of @John Kormylo):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portrait,margin=1cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{flowfram}% http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\newsavebox{\titlebox}
\setlength{\columnwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\columnsep}
\divide\columnwidth by 3
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\begin{lrbox}{\titlebox}% \maketitle inside \titlebox
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 2\columnwidth+\columnsep}%
  \@twocolumntrue
  \maketitle
  \small
  \begin{center}%
    {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
  \end{center}
  \itshape}% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BODY
{\bigskip
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \global\setbox\titlebox=\copy\titlebox
}
\makeatother

\title{\lipsum[1][1]}% must go before abstract

\author{%
    {\normalsize\bfseries Author Name} \\[1ex]
    \normalsize University Name \\
    }
    
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}% must go before flowfram setup
    \noindent \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{abstract}

% First page setup
\newstaticframe[1]{\dimexpr 2\columnwidth+\columnsep}{\dimexpr \ht\titlebox+\dp\titlebox}
  {0pt}{\dimexpr \textheight-\ht\titlebox-\dp\titlebox}[titleabstract]
\newflowframe[1]{\columnwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-\ht\titlebox-\dp\titlebox}
  {0pt}{0pt}[shortleftcolumn]
\newflowframe[1]{\columnwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-\ht\titlebox-\dp\titlebox}
  {\dimexpr \columnwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}[shortcentercolumn]

% Subsequent pages setup    
\newflowframe[>1]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}
  {0pt}{0pt}[leftcolumn]
\newflowframe[>1]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}
  {\dimexpr \columnwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}[centercolumn]
\newflowframe{\columnwidth}{\textheight}
  {\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnwidth}{0pt}[rightcolumn]

\begin{staticcontents*}{titleabstract}
  \box\titlebox
\end{staticcontents*}

% draw rules
\getflowid{\IDleft}{shortleftcolumn}
\getflowid{\IDright}{shortcentercolumn}
\insertvrule{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDright}
\let\IDleft=\IDright
\getflowid{\IDright}{rightcolumn}
\insertvrule{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDright}

\getflowid{\IDleft}{leftcolumn}
\getflowid{\IDright}{centercolumn}
\insertvrule{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDright}
\let\IDleft=\IDright
\getflowid{\IDright}{rightcolumn}
\insertvrule{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDright}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I have no idea where to begin with this problem. I hope the community does not mind me asking a question for which I have not attempted serious solutions not involving simple packages such as `flushend` due to not understanding the `flowfram` package.

**Edit 1:** After reading the `flowfram` package [annotated documentation pp. 180-181](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram/flowfram.pdf), it appears that

```
\insertvrule{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDright}
```

can be modified with optional arguments to extend the the vertical lines in the negative direction such as

```
\insertvrule[0pt][-18.3cm]{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDright}
```

which now gives:

[image]

This can be done manually if needs be but to modify my questions: 1) Is there a way for LaTeX to detect how far the text comes down the page without having to resort to manual distances guess (-18.3cm etc) and 2) is there a way to balance the triple columns within `flowfram`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since flowfram has to be set before the aux file is read, this writes a similar file `FFsetup.tex` which is read earlier.  It defines macros `\lastpage` and `\lastheight`.

The macro `\firstFFsetup` handles the case when there is suddenly fewer pages than before.  `\secondFFsetupe` handles the case when the number of pages is the same as before.  `\extraFFsetup` handles the case when there is now more text (which automatically goes to overflow pages).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portrait,margin=1cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{flowfram}% http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{refcount}

\newsavebox{\titlebox}
\setlength{\columnwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\columnsep}
\divide\columnwidth by 3

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\begin{lrbox}{\titlebox}% \maketitle inside \titlebox
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 2\columnwidth+\columnsep}%
  \@twocolumntrue
  \maketitle
  \small
  \begin{center}%
    {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
  \end{center}
  \itshape}% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BODY
{\bigskip
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \global\setbox\titlebox=\copy\titlebox
}
\makeatother

\title{\lipsum[1][1]}% must go before abstract

\author{%
    {\normalsize\bfseries Author Name} \\[1ex]
    \normalsize University Name \\
    }
    
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}% must go before flowfram setup
    \noindent \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{abstract}

% First page setup
\newstaticframe[1]{\dimexpr 2\columnwidth+\columnsep}{\dimexpr \ht\titlebox+\dp\titlebox}
  {0pt}{\dimexpr \textheight-\ht\titlebox-\dp\titlebox}[titleabstract]
\newflowframe[1]{\columnwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-\ht\titlebox-\dp\titlebox}
  {0pt}{0pt}[shortleftcolumn]
\newflowframe[1]{\columnwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-\ht\titlebox-\dp\titlebox}
  {\dimexpr \columnwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}[shortcentercolumn]
\newflowframe[1]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnwidth}{0pt}[shortrightcolumn]

\getflowid{\IDleft}{shortleftcolumn}
\getflowid{\IDcenter}{shortcentercolumn}
\getflowid{\IDright}{shortrightcolumn}
\insertvrule{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDcenter}
\insertvrule{flow}{\IDcenter}{flow}{\IDright}
  
\InputIfFileExists{FFsetup}{}{}% args not useful

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{lastpage}{% first time only
  \newflowframe[>1]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[leftcolumn]
  \newflowframe[>1]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \columnwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}[centercolumn]
  \newflowframe[>1]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnwidth}{0pt}[rightcolumn]
  \getflowid{\IDleft}{leftcolumn}
  \getflowid{\IDcenter}{centercolumn}
  \getflowid{\IDright}{rightcolumn}
  \insertvrule{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDcenter}
  \insertvrule{flow}{\IDcenter}{flow}{\IDright}%
}{% \lastpage and \lastheight defined
  \ifnum\lastpage>2\relax
    \newcommand{\nextlastpage}{\the\numexpr \lastpage-1}%
    \newflowframe[2-\nextlastpage]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[leftcolumn]%
    \newflowframe[2-\nextlastpage]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \columnwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}[centercolumn]%
    \newflowframe[2-\nextlastpage]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnwidth}{0pt}[rightcolumn]%
    \getflowid{\IDleft}{leftcolumn}%
    \getflowid{\IDcenter}{centercolumn}%
    \getflowid{\IDright}{rightcolumn}%
    \insertvrule{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDcenter}%
    \insertvrule{flow}{\IDcenter}{flow}{\IDright}%
  \fi
  \newflowframe[\lastpage]{\columnwidth}{\lastheight}
    {0pt}{\dimexpr \textheight-\lastheight}[topleftcolumn]%
  \newflowframe[\lastpage]{\columnwidth}{\lastheight}
    {\dimexpr \columnwidth+\columnsep}{\dimexpr \textheight-\lastheight}[topcentercolumn]
  \newflowframe[\lastpage]{\columnwidth}{\lastheight}
    {\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-\lastheight}[toprightcolumn]
  \getflowid{\IDleft}{topleftcolumn}%
  \getflowid{\IDcenter}{topcentercolumn}%
  \getflowid{\IDright}{toprightcolumn}%
  \insertvrule{flow}{\IDleft}{flow}{\IDcenter}%
  \insertvrule{flow}{\IDcenter}{flow}{\IDright}%
% excess text
  \newflowframe[>\lastpage]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}%
  \newflowframe[>\lastpage]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \columnwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}%
  \newflowframe[>\lastpage]{\columnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnwidth}{0pt}%
}

\newcommand{\firstFFsetup}{% first time
  \edef\lastpage{\arabic{page}}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr \textheight-\pagegoal+\pagetotal+2\baselineskip\relax
  \ifnum\value{displayedframe}>1 \advance\dimen0 by \textheight \fi
  \ifnum\value{displayedframe}>2 \advance\dimen0 by \textheight \fi
  \count1=\numexpr \dimen0/\baselineskip\relax
  \divide\count1 by 3
  \dimen0=\baselineskip
  \multiply\dimen0 by \count1
  \edef\lastheight{\the\dimen0}}

\newcommand{\secondFFsetup}{% same last page
  \dimen0=\dimexpr \lastheight-\pagegoal+\pagetotal+2\baselineskip\relax
  \ifnum\value{displayedframe}>1 \advance\dimen0 by \lastheight \fi
  \ifnum\value{displayedframe}>2 \advance\dimen0 by \lastheight \fi
  \count1=\numexpr \dimen0/\baselineskip\relax
  \divide\count1 by 3
  \dimen0=\baselineskip
  \multiply\dimen0 by \count1
  \edef\lastheight{\the\dimen0}}
  
\newcommand{\extraFFsetup}{% extra pages
  \dimen0=\lastheight\relax
  \multiply\dimen0 by 3
  \advance\dimen0 by \dimexpr \textheight-\pagegoal+\pagetotal+2\baselineskip\relax
  \ifnum\value{displayedframe}>1 \advance\dimen0 by \textheight \fi
  \ifnum\value{displayedframe}>2 \advance\dimen0 by \textheight \fi
  \count1=\value{page}%
  \ifdim\dimen0<3\textheight\relax
    \advance\count1 by -1
  \else
    \advance\dimen0 by -3\textheight
  \fi
  \edef\lastpage{\number\count1}%
  \count1=\numexpr \dimen0/\baselineskip\relax
  \divide\count1 by 3
  \dimen0=\baselineskip
  \multiply\dimen0 by \count1
  \edef\lastheight{\the\dimen0}}

\AtEndDocument{\@ifundefined{lastpage}{% first time
  \firstFFsetup
}{%
  \ifnum\lastpage>\value{page}\relax
    \firstFFsetup
  \else\ifnum\lastpage=\value{page}\relax
      \secondFFsetup
    \else
      \extraFFsetup
    \fi
  \fi
}%
  \newwrite\FFid
  \immediate\openout\FFid=FFsetup
  \immediate\write\FFid{\string\gdef\string\lastpage{\lastpage}}%
  \immediate\write\FFid{\string\gdef\string\lastheight{\lastheight}}%\thedisplayedframe
  \closeout\FFid}
\makeatother

\begin{staticcontents*}{titleabstract}
  \box\titlebox
\end{staticcontents*}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Accepted and upvoted as it did as required although I still cannot work out how to balance the columns - it's sad that `flushend` and `balance` only work on two columns! Might need to look at the `multicol` .sty file to see how that balances multiple columns, doesn't seem possible in `flowfram`. Thanks for the answers you have provided.

Comment: To no-one in particular, a crude method to balance the final page is to manually insert ` \newpage \noindent\` on text until the columns are balanced. Not sure how to do this with bibliography entries if used but at least there is a method.

Comment: Alas, multicol and frowfram appear to be incompatible,  Even loading both at the same time causes major problems.

Comment: Yeah the packages broke on me whilst using them too. I adapted your first answer and asked a new question regarding [how to break biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637273/245306) so that they could be balanced, your second answer worked in my main document too, appreciate it.

Comment: The main problem is that flowfram is set up before the aux file is read, so there is no way to communicate the information needed.  Unless you used a different file...

Comment: I was wondering if one could set up flowfram using `\AtBeginDocument`, but no joy.

Comment: Thank you for trying. It is an incredibly good package for custom layouts but it's extremely fidgety and the manual is quite bright to look at. Even float pages require custom flowpages, really impressive package but complicated. I appreciate your time with this package and questions, I'm going to learn it better as it is useful.

Comment: I replaced both versions with a new one which (finally) does what you want.  It still takes two runs to adjust to changes.

Comment: Thank you, that's genuinely amazing and everything I needed rather than doing it manually, I appreciate the time and effort you put into so gave a bounty.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Really such a nice work, is it possible to place the figure upto two column and three column, please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi yeah I was going to open a new question on that issue, it looks like new flowframes need to be setup for each page the table or figure on which is unfortunate. If the figure or table environment could force itself in and wrap text then that would be incredible but probably a new question is needed.

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor Thanks for your comment, if you open a new question, kindly share the link to me (anyhow, I'm looking this cite continuously...)