# Biblatex - Annote field \newpage without \finentry punctuation

Tags: biblatex

**Problem:** Following on from [attempts to automatically balance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637145/245306) the end of a `flowfram` 3 column document, I have came to the conclusion that balancing must be done manually. When using the `annote` field of biblatex entries to manually insert `\newpage` so that manual balancing can be performed, the `\finentry` punctuation appears at the end of the reference and at the end of the `annote` field (which contains solely a LaTeX command). This is causing spaces and a fullstop that is undesirable (highlighted in yellow):

[image]

**What I have tried:**

I tried using the `biblatex` command `\iffieldundef` as such:

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{annotation}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}
  \finentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}
   \printfield{annotation}%
   \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
   \finentry}
}
```

This is causing the following error:

```
Overfull \hbox (3.90202pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 601--601
[][]\T1/cmr/m/n/8 (-20) Adolf-Bryfogle, J. et al. \T1/cmr/m/it/8 (-20) Curr. Op
in. Struct.
! pdfTeX error (ext1): \pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode.
\close@pdflink ...\Hy@VerboseLinkStop \pdfendlink 
                                                  
l.601 ...c,title=\notessize{REFERENCES AND NOTES}]
                                                  
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I am assuming that it is caused by me hyperlinking the bibliography entries to their DOI, the annote field is also hyperlinked to the DOI so I think that it is breaking it somehow.

**What I would like:** For the error message to be resolved, manual `\newpage` to be permitted so that a 3 column document can be balanced at the end and or another method to manually insert column or page breaks into the biblatex entries if possible.

**MWEB:**

```
% arara: clean: {extensions: [abb, abrn, aux, bbl, bib, bcf, blg, glg, glo, gls, ist, log, nom, ntn, run.xml,def,dfn]}
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: clean: {extensions: [abb, abrn, aux, bbl, bib, bcf, blg, glg, glo, gls, ist, log, nom, ntn, run.xml,def,dfn]}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref=true,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@article{Dahi97,
doi = {10.1126/science.278.5335.82},
issn = {0036-8075},
journal = {Science},
number = {5335},
pages = {82--87},
publisher = {American Association for the Advancement of Science},
title = {{De Novo Protein Design: Fully Automated Sequence Selection}},
url = {https://science.sciencemag.org/content/278/5335/82},
volume = {278},
year = {1997}
}
@Article{Daws19,
  author   = {Dawson, William M and Rhys, Guto G and Woolfson, Derek N},
  journal  = {Curr. Opin. Chem. Biol.},
  title    = {{Towards functional de novo designed proteins}},
  year     = {2019},
  annote   = {\newpage},
  issn     = {1367-5931},
  pages    = {102--111},
  volume   = {52},
  doi      = {10.1016/j.cbpa.2019.06.011},
  url      = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1367593119300043},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

% To remove then re-add the period at the end of references
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{annotation}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}
  \finentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}
   \printfield{annotation}%
   \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
   \finentry}
}

% For hyperlinking references to DOI or URL - Cannot remember TeXSE Question obtained from, apologies
\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%
    \iffieldundef{doi}
        {\iffieldundef{url}
            {#1}
            {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
        {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}
}

\makeatletter
    \def\blx@driver#1{%
        \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@#1}
            {\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@#1}}}
            {\ifcsdef{blx@bbx@*}
                {\blx@warning{%
                    No driver for entry type '#1'.\MessageBreak
                    Using fallback driver}%
                    \usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@*}}
                }
                {\blx@error
                    {No driver found}
                    {I can't find a driver for the entry type
                    '\abx@field@entrytype'\MessageBreak
                    and there is no fallback driver either}}
                }
}
\makeatother        

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-2]
\cite{Daws19}
\cite{Dahi97}

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you are basically doing `\href{some-url}{abc\newpage}` and hyperref really doesn't like that.

I wouldn't put the \newpage inside the bib, that is obviously not a feature of the entry. I would suggest to redefine the bibliography environment so that you can add newpage before some entries. E.g.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref=true,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@article{Dahi97,
doi = {10.1126/science.278.5335.82},
issn = {0036-8075},
journal = {Science},
number = {5335},
pages = {82--87},
publisher = {American Association for the Advancement of Science},
title = {{De Novo Protein Design: Fully Automated Sequence Selection}},
url = {https://science.sciencemag.org/content/278/5335/82},
volume = {278},
year = {1997}
}
@Article{Daws19,
  author   = {Dawson, William M and Rhys, Guto G and Woolfson, Derek N},
  journal  = {Curr. Opin. Chem. Biol.},
  title    = {{Towards functional de novo designed proteins}},
  year     = {2019},
  issn     = {1367-5931},
  pages    = {102--111},
  volume   = {52},
  doi      = {10.1016/j.cbpa.2019.06.011},
  url      = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1367593119300043},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{example.bib}


% For hyperlinking references to DOI or URL - Cannot remember TeXSE Question obtained from, apologies
\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%
    \iffieldundef{doi}
        {\iffieldundef{url}
            {#1}
            {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
        {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}
}

\makeatletter
    \def\blx@driver#1{%
        \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@#1}
            {\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@#1}}}
            {\ifcsdef{blx@bbx@*}
                {\blx@warning{%
                    No driver for entry type '#1'.\MessageBreak
                    Using fallback driver}%
                    \usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\csuse{blx@bbx@*}}
                }
                {\blx@error
                    {No driver found}
                    {I can't find a driver for the entry type
                    '\abx@field@entrytype'\MessageBreak
                    and there is no fallback driver either}}
                }%
}
\makeatother


\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\csname optionalnewpage-\thefield{entrykey}\endcsname\item}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{optionalnewpage-Dahi97}{\newpage}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-2]
\cite{Daws19}
\cite{Dahi97}

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Yes, to anyone else who reads this, if you're using 2 columns then use `balance` or `flushend` packages but if you need a method to balance 3 columns and the references are at the end (which is my main document) then this method works really well.