tcolorbox in a multicol environment sometimes breaks in the wrong place
When I put several tcolorbox boxes in a multicol environment, sometimes they break in the wrong place. In the example below, in the second column, the break in the first box needn't be there. Likewise in the second box of the third column.

This is produced by
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}
{
    enhanced,breakable,lines before break=5,
    enlarge bottom at break by=.6cm,
    enlarge top at break by=.6cm,
    overlay first={\node[anchor=north east] at (frame.south east) {Continued\dots};},
    overlay last={\node[anchor=south west] at (frame.north west) {\dots Continued};}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{tcolorbox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam euismod, tellus aliquet interdum ultrices, lectus lorem molestie purus, a scelerisque nulla nisl eu neque. Donec interdum et risus non euismod. Vivamus luctus lacus vitae ipsum placerat condimentum. Donec turpis ipsum, euismod id nulla sit amet, venenatis euismod nisi. Phasellus sed dui mattis, porta augue ac, congue nisl. Curabitur in massa ac nisl porta tempus ut sit amet eros. Morbi pharetra sem id ornare tristique. Aliquam faucibus quis neque vulputate aliquet. Mauris rutrum dui non risus faucibus malesuada. Maecenas consectetur libero eget augue viverra, id suscipit enim mollis. Praesent ullamcorper leo varius nisl fermentum suscipit.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam euismod, tellus aliquet interdum ultrices, lectus lorem molestie purus, a scelerisque nulla nisl eu neque. Donec interdum et risus non euismod. Vivamus luctus lacus vitae ipsum placerat condimentum. Donec turpis ipsum, euismod id nulla sit amet, venenatis euismod nisi. Phasellus sed dui mattis, porta augue ac, congue nisl.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam euismod, tellus aliquet interdum ultrices, lectus lorem molestie purus, a scelerisque nulla nisl eu neque. Donec interdum et risus non euismod. Vivamus luctus lacus vitae ipsum placerat condimentum. Donec turpis ipsum, euismod id nulla sit amet, venenatis euismod nisi. Phasellus sed dui mattis, porta augue ac, congue nisl.
\end{mybox}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}

The still issue occurs with the enlarge bottom at break, enlarge top at break, overlay first and overlay last options removed, so I have left these in to demonstrate the issue more clearly.
Please forgive me not using the lipsum package to shorten the MWE - I needed finer control to produce the issue, which only occurs under certain conditions.
I have discovered this issue by programatically 'weaving' 100s of Rnw reports (in RStudio) of student feedback. Each of these boxes each represents one student comment in the report. While most comments are short (and so the three-column format works nicely), occasionally there are reports with longer comments, like in this MWE, and this seems to be when the issue arises. I also wrap the comments in a lstlisting environment (within each tcolorbox) to avoid issues with special characters (like &). I only mention this for context, and even when all this is stripped out (as per the MWE), the issue still occurs.
Most of the time, it works perfectly, as in the case shown below (breaking across the bottom of the second column to the top of the third column), with the breaks only occurring at the end of columns.
Is there anything I can do to stop the issue shown in the first image occurring? Thank you!


Muilticols actually creates one column which is (in this case) 3\textheight high, then breaks it into three columns.  This interferes with tcolorbox which does its own column breaking,

Here is a flowfram way to create 3 columns.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\newlength{\mycolumnwidth}
\setlength{\mycolumnwidth}{\dimexpr (\textwidth-2\columnsep)/3}
\newflowframe{\mycolumnwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe{\mycolumnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \mycolumnwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}
\newflowframe{\mycolumnwidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\mycolumnwidth}{0pt}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}
{
    enhanced,breakable,lines before break=5,
    enlarge bottom at break by=.6cm,
    enlarge top at break by=.6cm,
    overlay first={\node[anchor=north east] at (frame.south east) {Continued\dots};},
    overlay last={\node[anchor=south west] at (frame.north west) {\dots Continued};}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam euismod, tellus aliquet interdum ultrices, lectus lorem molestie purus, a scelerisque nulla nisl eu neque. Donec interdum et risus non euismod. Vivamus luctus lacus vitae ipsum placerat condimentum. Donec turpis ipsum, euismod id nulla sit amet, venenatis euismod nisi. Phasellus sed dui mattis, porta augue ac, congue nisl. Curabitur in massa ac nisl porta tempus ut sit amet eros. Morbi pharetra sem id ornare tristique. Aliquam faucibus quis neque vulputate aliquet. Mauris rutrum dui non risus faucibus malesuada. Maecenas consectetur libero eget augue viverra, id suscipit enim mollis. Praesent ullamcorper leo varius nisl fermentum suscipit.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam euismod, tellus aliquet interdum ultrices, lectus lorem molestie purus, a scelerisque nulla nisl eu neque. Donec interdum et risus non euismod. Vivamus luctus lacus vitae ipsum placerat condimentum. Donec turpis ipsum, euismod id nulla sit amet, venenatis euismod nisi. Phasellus sed dui mattis, porta augue ac, congue nisl.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fringilla mollis convallis. Vivamus venenatis purus eget purus facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam euismod, tellus aliquet interdum ultrices, lectus lorem molestie purus, a scelerisque nulla nisl eu neque. Donec interdum et risus non euismod. Vivamus luctus lacus vitae ipsum placerat condimentum. Donec turpis ipsum, euismod id nulla sit amet, venenatis euismod nisi. Phasellus sed dui mattis, porta augue ac, congue nisl.
\end{mybox}

\end{document}


This looks like a very powerful package, and one that I'd not seen before. I've been experimenting with it but customising it seems very difficult to me. Is it possible to balance the columns like in multicols (i.e., flush end)? Is it possible to switch between single-column and three-column format (the number of pages in each may vary). I did find your helpful answer here, but am still struggling to apply it to my case:

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637145/flowfram-package-balance-3-columns-and-extend-columnsep-line-to-end-of-text
