Small breakable tcolorbox in multicol creates an empty column
I have a small breakable tcolorbox in a multicol environment. The box is small enough to not need to be broken. When it follows a title or another box, if the flow of text places them just at the beginning of a column, then the box is positioned on the next page, leaving an empty column, as seen in this MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{
    breakable,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1-1]

\lipsum[1][1-14]

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    breakable,
]
some text here
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}


The problem disappears when I remove the breakable option.
The documentation of tcolorbox says using it with multicol can be troublesome, but I didn't find anything related to this behavior. Besides using breakable only when needed, what could be done to avoid this behavior?

You can use \raggedcolumns in the multicols environment, which solves this effect.

This does not work with this MWE.

Really not good, sorry.

And the ignore nobreak option of the tcolorbox environment?

Seriously, don't use breakable tcolorboxes with multicols.  They each try to break column separately.  Multicols really has only one column per page, which it breaks into two columns at the end.

@hair-splitter It works for this example, but messes the vertical align pretty bad in my full case.

@JohnKormylo I initially just wanted to have breakable color boxes, which led me to tcolorbox.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/721251/tcolorbox-in-a-multicol-environment-sometimes-breaks-in-the-wrong-place
