# Double column layout, left side for text, right side for listings

Tags: page-breaking, multicol, flowfram

For a documentation I am having a special chapter where there are a lot of code listings, compared to the amount of prose text. What I would like to end up with is a two column layout, where the left column is used for the prose text only and the right column is used for code listings only.

The following creates a two page double column document, where the left column always says FOO and the right column only says BAR.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent        \multido{}{322}{FOO }  \multido{}{322}{BAR }
        \multido{}{322}{FOO } \multido{}{322}{BAR }
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

I want the same effect, but without manually chopping up my input. I want a macro and/or an environment which I tell `\multido{}{644}{FOO }` and `\multido{}{644}{BAR }` and it automagically does the page/column breaking as illustrated by the example above.

Is there an environment that does this? Does anybody see a simple and quickway to achieving this?

---

**WIP:**

I've been trying a hack or two, but kept failing. The thing is, a page break in the left column must make the text continue in the left column of the next page. A page break in the right column must make the listings continue in the right column of the next page. My core idea was I have two "input-saveboxes" A and B and whenever LaTeX encounters a column break in a `multicols` environment it switches over to the other input-savebox.

But I never got close to implement anything like that. My best looking attemt was `\hsize=.5\hsize` and use `\makebox` to generate boxes that have neither width, nor height nor depth, but contain other boxes which carefully place the listings. Using this approach I cannot make listings break at the end of pages/columns.

There may be a way using a combination of `flowfram` as described [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85581/10478) and `multicols`:

- have a `multicols` with one column inside a `staticcontent` environment
- bewitch `\pagebreak` inside the `multicolumn` environment to do a `\continueonframe` in combination with `\refstepcounter`

I'll try this next while hoping for a ready to use solution ...

**Update**

The bewitching `\pagebreak` idea was based on some properties I thought the `multicols` environment had. Seems like I only immagined those. I still think multicols could be hacked to do what I want, because it already follows the approach of eating away form `\box\partial@page`. By adding a prefilled second box for partial pages and alternating output this could be done. However, this is a bigger project I won't be able to complete in time. And I'm still guessing a lot, because my TeX is not that good and reading Frank's TeX is almost as challenging as reading Perl code.

Comment: a similar question was asked on the texhax list in march 2010, albeit for facing pages.  these postings may be helpful: [texhax: Multiple documents within a document](http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2010-March/014542.html) and the answer at http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2010-March/014546.html

Comment: The simplest thing usually is to use a single column layout with `\textsize` reduced to one column width, then increase `\marginparwidth` by the same amount, then you can put your listings in the margin using standard marginpar or one of the packages that re-implement that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks! `\vsplit` is the command that might help a lot. @DavidCarlisle: I couldn't find marginpar implementations that could do pagebreaks.

Comment: @user1129682 well we can always make one...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is a bit rough but may get you started. It assumes there are no floats, it also doesn't reposition the page head and foot over both columns (`fancyhdr` could help with that) and it's probably incompatible with something,...

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.x}
\
\\\
\\\\\
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
some code [
here}
&& here
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file2.x}
<math>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>a</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>b</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
</math>
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\addtolength\textwidth{-6cm}
\addtolength\marginparwidth{6cm}

\def\a{One two three four five six. }
\def\b{\a\a\begin{equation}\theequation=\theequation\end{equation} \roman{equation} \roman{equation} \roman{equation} \a}
\def\c{Red yellow blue green black white. }

\makeatletter
\def \@combinefloats {%
\ifvoid\rightcol\else
\global\setbox\@ne\vsplit\rightcol to \textheight
\global\setbox\@ne\vbox to \textheight{\unvbox\@ne\vss}%
\setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\box\@outputbox\kern\marginparsep\box\@ne}}%
\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{listings}

\newbox\rightcol
\setbox\rightcol\vbox{}
\def\addlisting#1{\global\setbox\rightcol\vbox{{\hsize\marginparwidth\linewidth\hsize\columnwidth\hsize\unvbox\rightcol\smallskip#1\par}}}

\begin{document}

\b\c\b
\addlisting{\lstinputlisting{file1.x}}
\c\c
\addlisting{\lstinputlisting{file2.x}}
\c\b\b\a\a\b\c\c\a
\a\c\c\c\c\c\b\b\b\a\b\c\c\a


\end{document}
```