# Two column-wide figure in 4 column enviroment

Tags: graphics, positioning, columns, posters

I have poster with 4 columns. I want to place figure in the middle of poster, that should be only 2 columns wide. I am using the `a0poster` package. So I have something like this:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4} 
Some text

\begin{figure}[H]% This figure should be two columns wide

\end{figure}
More text
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using some ideas from [Three-columns text with figures of 2`\columnwidth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70175/5764), [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) can assist in flowing your text around images in a specific (recti-linear) layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{a0poster}% http://ctan.org/pkg/a0poster
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{flowfram,graphicx,microtype}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{flowfram,graphicx,microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\newlength{\blockwidth}\setlength{\blockwidth}{.24\textwidth}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\dimexpr.01333\textwidth}

\newlength{\imageheight}\setlength{\imageheight}{.3\textheight}

\newflowframe{0.24\textwidth}{\textheight}
  {0pt}{0pt}[columnone]

\newflowframe{0.24\textwidth}{\dimexpr.5\textheight-.5\imageheight-\columnsep}
  {\dimexpr\blockwidth+\columnsep}{\dimexpr.5\textheight+.5\imageheight+\columnsep}[columntwoTOP]
\newflowframe{0.24\textwidth}{\dimexpr.5\textheight-.5\imageheight-\columnsep}
  {\dimexpr\blockwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}[columntwoBOT]

\newflowframe{0.24\textwidth}{\dimexpr.5\textheight-.5\imageheight-\columnsep}
  {\dimexpr2\blockwidth+2\columnsep}{\dimexpr.5\textheight+.5\imageheight+\columnsep}[columnthreeTOP]
\newflowframe{0.24\textwidth}{\dimexpr.5\textheight-.5\imageheight-\columnsep}
  {\dimexpr2\blockwidth+2\columnsep}{0pt}[columnthreeBOT]

\newflowframe{0.24\textwidth}{\textheight}
  {\dimexpr3\blockwidth+3\columnsep}{0pt}[columnfour]

\newstaticframe{\dimexpr2\blockwidth+\columnsep}{\imageheight}
{\dimexpr\blockwidth+\columnsep}{\dimexpr.5\textheight-.5\imageheight}[centerfigure]

\title{\textbf{Flowfram poster}}
\author{by Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{staticcontents*}{centerfigure}
\includegraphics[
  width=\dimexpr2\blockwidth+\columnsep,
  height=\imageheight]{example-image-a}
\end{staticcontents*}

\lipsum[2-33]

\end{document}
```

The above MWE creates 6 dynamic frames (`columnone` and `columntwo` span the entire `\textheight`, while `columntwoTOP`/`BOT` and `columnthreeTOP`/`BOT` span whatever's left after inserting the image. Technically, all you need to do is change the height of the image (set `\imageheight`), and everything else should fall into place. Of course, I assume you're only inserting an image (not a caption as well, but that could be changed).

The image is contained inside a "static frame" called `centerfigure` that spans exactly 2 columns (including the column separation/gap).

Answer (score 2):

For a poster some manual spacing seems acceptable, this just positions the figure wherever you want, then add two vertical spaces in the text to make space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\a{One two three four five six. }
\def\b{Red yellow green blue white black grey purple pink. }
\def\c{\a\b\b\a\a\a\b\b\a\b}
\def\d{\c\c\a\a\b\a\b}
\usepackage{multicol,capt-of}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(82,-300){\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{5cm}
\captionof{figure}{a picture of somethimg}
\end{minipage}}}
\end{picture}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\d

aa zzz bbb\\[7cm]
\c\a

yyyy yyy yyy yyy yyy \\[7cm]
\d\d\d\d\d\d


More text
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```