# Alternative to multicol that allows floating figures

Tags: floats, multicol

I have three columns landscape layout, and I need to be able to use floating figures, because otherwise I have arbitrary paragraph breaks where I can insert a `[H]` figure, and then the columns do not spread out correctly, and I cannot insert arbitrary line breaks to place the figures.

What alternatives to `multicol` exists that can have a floating figure (width of a column, height of less than the column) that don't force me to fiddle around with line breaks and justification?

Comment: you could try a single column layout with pages set to the size of your columns then arrange to put three pages per page using a n-up re-arrangement after the pdf is made

Comment: The alternatives are a two column layout without multicol,   a 3x1 page as David suggested (easy whith pdfpages, for instance) or use [flowfram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73572/11604). The advantage of the last packages is that you can have floats but also non-floating figures not limited to column widths, although this will need be more on charge of the final layout.