# How to typeset a wide figure spanning multiple columns in a 'sciposter' documentclass?

Tags: environments, multicolumn, flowfram

i need to make a figure span two or three columns inside a sciposter documentclass, and be positioned at the bottom of the page (not flowing)

Comment: Can you provide a base document we as a community can work with?

Comment: @Werner see my answer

Comment: One can always let one column overlap the others using \vfill\noindent\rlap{...}

Comment: @JohnKormylo does it only stand true for `tabular` environments?

Comment: @ivan866 - With tabular it is easier to use \multicolumn.  No overlap needed.

Answer (score 1):

this is a solution with `flowfram` package, based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73572/175664) thread; notice it requires manually presetting the frame sizes and locations, but after that, works as magic

```
\documentclass[a1,landscape]{sciposter}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\newflowframe[1]{0.33\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}
{0pt}{.1\textheight}[col1]
\newflowframe[1]{0.33\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}
{0.34\textwidth}{.1\textheight}[col2]
\newflowframe[1]{0.33\textwidth}{\textheight}
{0.67\textwidth}{.1\textheight}[col3]
\newstaticframe[1]{\textwidth}{.1\textheight}
{0pt}{.9\textheight}[frm1]
\newstaticframe[1]{0.66\textwidth}{.1\textheight}
{0pt}{0pt}[frm2]

\title{poster title}

\begin{document}
\begin{staticcontents*}{frm1}
\maketitle
\end{staticcontents*}

\part{part I}
text 1
\section{section 1}
text 2
\begin{staticcontents*}{frm2}
\begin{figure}
    \centering{\includegraphics[width=5in]{c:/img/img01}}
    \caption{figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{staticcontents*}
\end{document}
```